# MvvmCross Dialog Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, navigation-drawer

I have found a good blogpost on using this in MvvmCross but I want to use this in an MvvmCross Monodroid.Dialog application. Has anyone managed to get this to work?

I have the following in my Action:

```
Root = new RootElement{ 
    new Section{
        new ViewElement("page_home_view")
    }
};
```

and have made sure that `page_home_view.axml` and `item_menu.axml` are in the layout folder.

However I get the following error:

```
[Android.Dialog] Inflate failed: Didn't find class "Mvx.MvxListView" on path: /data/app/SomeApp.Mobile.Droid-1.apk
[Android.Dialog] ViewElement: Failed to load resource: page_home_view
```

At the moment I just want to get a dialog opening with the layout there so I can add all of the functionality after.

Why would it not know what `MvxListView` is?

Here is the full XML for the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /> <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MenuItems; ItemClick SelectMenuItemCommand"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_menu"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111" /> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[UPDATE]

Ok so I cant call `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.page_home_view);` from a monodroid.dialog mvvmcross activity.

I now have the following in my dialog activity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.page_home_view);

        var bindings = this.CreateInlineBindingTarget<CategoriesViewModel>();

        Root = new RootElement{ 
            new BindableSection<CustomViewElement>(string.Empty, () => new CustomViewElement(this))
                .Bind(bindings, element => element.ItemsSource, vm => vm.Categories),
            };


        this.ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        this.ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled (true);

        var view  = this.BindingInflate (Resource.Layout.page_home_view, null);



        this._drawer = view.FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        this._drawerList = view.FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.left_drawer);

        _drawer.SetDrawerShadow(Resource.Drawable.drawer_shadow_dark, (int)GravityFlags.Start);

        this._drawerToggle = new MyActionBarDrawerToggle(this, _drawer,
            Resource.Drawable.ic_drawer_light,
            Resource.String.drawer_open,
            Resource.String.drawer_close);

        //You can alternatively use _drawer.DrawerClosed here
        this._drawerToggle.DrawerClosed += delegate
        {
            //this.ActionBar.Title = this._title;
            this.InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        };


        //You can alternatively use _drawer.DrawerOpened here
        this._drawerToggle.DrawerOpened += delegate
        {
            //this.ActionBar.Title = this._drawerTitle;
            this.InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        };

        _drawer.SetDrawerListener(this._drawerToggle);
    }
```

However nothing is wired up...

Clicking the button in the actionbar does nothing.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that I need to add fragment support to monodroid.dialog in order for this to work. Am I right in that assumption?

Comment: What was the link to the blog post you mentioned at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you forgot to define local namespace?

```
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Make sure that in the root node of your XML file you define XML namespaces, see example below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Comment: Added the full xml for the view in question.